# Angular 2 how do i get the latest updated value from a service to component

Tags: angular

How do I get updated value from a service to component. Below I am trying to get the showValues from ConnectService to MasterComponent.

```
export class MasterComponent{
public showValue:string;
constructor(public connectService: ConnectService, public _router: Router){
if(localStorage.getItem("clientStatus")=='connected'){
this.showValue = this.connectService.showValues;
    console.log("MasterComponent",this.showValue);
}
}
```

from below service i want to update the component.

```
export class ConnectService{
  public showValues: string;
constructor(){
}
recvNotify(m) {
//getting value
buttonName = innervalue;
                console.log("ELSEinnervalue",buttonName);
                switch (buttonName) {
                    case "0x01010000":
                        console.log('showValue==1');

                        this.showValues = "1";
                    break;
                    case "0x01020000":
                        console.log('showValue==2');
                        this.showValues = "2";   
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log('showValue==3');
                         this.showValues = "3";  
                    }
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EventEmitter` as a notifier for any component

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private emitter: EventEmitter<any>;
  constructor() {
    this.emitter = new EventEmitter<any>();
  }
  getEmitter(): EventEmitter<any> {
    return this.emitter;
  }
  emit(data: any): void {
    this.emitter.emit(data);
  }
}
```

and subscribe to event in components like this and update anything

```
@Component({
 template: ''
})
export class MyComponent{
 constructor(private emitter: SharedService){
   this.emitter.getEmitter().subscribe(e => {
    // do stuff here
   });
 }
}
```

dont forget to add it to NgModule and use it as like services. the second way is use `Subject` from `rxjs`

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  public notifier: Observable<any>;
  public source: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>;
  constructor(){
   this.notifier = this.source.asObservable();
  }

  emit(data: any): void {
    this.source.next(data);
  }
}
```

Then in components

```
export class MyComponent{
 constructor(private service: SharedService){
   this.service.notifier.subscribe(e => {
    // do stuff here
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to just update a variable from my service. is there any simple way to do this

Comment: This is the basic way only two things can used as a notifier on is EventEmitter and second is Observable using Subject